# I'm having problems while unwrapping uv's from some meshes I have

Tags: uv-image-editor

They will either not update or become a mess if I reset them before. I'm using correct seams, I have tried appending the meshes to a new file, I've even sent the file to another PC wondering it could be a bug with my blender, but none has worked. I think it maybe has to do with my file settings, but only the meshes seem to fail, while not having overlapped topology or any other common problems. It happens with all of the separate meshes oxcept for the pigtail for some strange reason. I've also applied all transforms to all of them.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried applying the mirror modifier?

Comment: @BK.yep, and other modifiers and still the same problem

Comment: @vklidu sure, I kind of worked around it with a lightmap, which for some reason was the only way it unwrapped decently, but it comes with the problems you would expect from a lightmap (texture bleeding so I need a bigger texture, among others). 
At this point I really want to know why it happened, because I wouldn't want it again, plus I just followed my usual workflow which hasn't caused me any problems.

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6dMbkA4P" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6dMbkA4P/)

Comment: Btw, I'm trying to texture paint, and only the geometry that wouldn't unwrapp correctly paints as if I had an airbrush with texture, which is kind of annoying, but not a mayor problem, I'm just wondering if there is any kind of relation there

Answer (score 0):

Those mentioned parts of UV are [Pinned](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/uv/editing.html#pin-unpin).
(vertices marked red)

[image]

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to Unpin and Unwrap <kbd>U</kbd> again :)

[image]